# AjaxStatus not working with dialog

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a ajaxstatus and dialog which is used for searching

```
<h:body>
    <p:ajaxStatus onstart="statusDialog.show();" onsuccess="statusDialog.hide();"/>  

    <p:dialog id="loading" modal="true" widgetVar="statusDialog" header="" draggable="false" closable="false">  
        <p:graphicImage value="/images/ajax-loader.gif" />  
    </p:dialog>
```

Dialog Part

```
<p:dialog id="showDial" header="Search" widgetVar="srch" resizable="false" >
                    <h:panelGrid id="searchGrid" columns="2" cellpadding="10" >
                        <h:outputLabel id="srchIdLbl" value="Employee ID:" />
                        <p:inputText id="srchIdTxt" value="#{employee.employeeId}" />

                        <p:commandButton id="search1" value="Search" type="submit" action ="#{employee.search()}" 
                                         update="patientTbl"/>
                        <p:commandButton id="reset1" value="Reset" type="reset" /> 
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:dialog>
```

the above code works fine, it displays the loading dialog. But once the search is completed the dialog will remain in the screen.
I added the below code in the commandButton id="search1" to close the dialog

```
onComplete="showDialog.hide()"
```

**Problem:**If i add the above line the AjaxStatus is not shown. I want to know why its not displaying.

I also tried adding the below code to the commandButton id="search1"

```
onclick="statusDialog.show()" onselect="statusDialog.show()" onmousedown="statusDialog.show()" onComplete="showDialog.hide() statusDialog.hide()"
```

**Problem** In the above code the background to dialog is disabled until the ManagedBeans code is completed and the dialog also closes but when i click the search button it loads with the previously entered search parameter even on clicking the reset button the data doesn't go.

How do i overcome the above problem of the previously entered data not going or how can i do the Ajaxstatus in a better way to avoid the above problems.